# jQuery trigger on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a project to write an API, the client will put my code in his HTML. example:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "test.js";
    // Use any selector
   $("body").append(s);
});
</script>
```

I attached some events on inputs eg:

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () {})
```

when i trigger the change event it works, but when the client load another jQuery library which will load after my code with AJAX, the trigger event stop working on load.

can any one help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: And why would the client load *another* jQuery library! That's an error, you should only have one version of jQuery loaded, with the exception of using noConflict etc.

Comment: Why are you loading another jQuery library?

Comment: Loading another jQuery library will also loose all plugins. As adeneo mentioned this is no good idea at all

Comment: I'm not loading two jQuery libraries, the client load them. In my api, i check if there is jQuery, if not then i attach jQuery to the HTML

Comment: @SaifAdnan - Then the client is doing it wrong, and there's nothing you can do to rectify other peoples stupidity.

Comment: Indeed the solution is to tell your client not to load an extra jQuery.

Comment: Pretty simple really.  You either need to get the client to stop doing stupid things that kill your code OR you need to change your code so it does not depend upon your client doing things properly with jQuery (like perhaps not depend upon jQuery at all).  Simple event handlers certainly don't need jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify to the client that if they load jQuery they must do so before your script so your script can use their jQuery.

Or, you can load your own jQuery into a different namespace using `jQuery.noConflict` : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery_my_version = jQuery.noConfilict();
jQuery_my_version (document).ready(function ($) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "test.js";
    // Use any selector
   $("body").append(s);
});
</script>
```

Then somewhere else attach your inputs, but not using $.

```
<script>
jQuery_my_version(document).on("change", "input", function () {})
</script>
```

But best practice, when we use many versions of jQuery of many libraries that uses $ is to wrap all code with anonymous functions like

```
(function($){
   //my super code
})(jQuery_my_version)
```

because **$** is easier to understand (to read, to type, etc), and necessary version of jQuery is *safely* used.

Answer (score -1):

This is issue of jQuery. Only 1 jQuery library on page.
If you can talk to client and set eqal jQuery version, you and your client can load jQuery library in that way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var jQueryScriptOutputted = false;
       function initJQuery() {

             //if the jQuery object isn't available
             if (typeof (jQuery) == 'undefined') {

                    if (!jQueryScriptOutputted) {
                           //only output the script once..
                           jQueryScriptOutputted = true;

                           //output the script
                           document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/_layouts/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"></scr" + "ipt>");
                    }
                    setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
             }

       }
       initJQuery();

</script>
```

It helped me in sharepoint, when sometimes I have 1 web part on the page, and other time I have 2-6 web parts in the same page.